# How to add background image in <textarea> tag?

Tags: html

I have HTML page where I'm using text box as  tag.I want to add background image to the text box.Can you please help me how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include this css in your code

```css
textarea {
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/500/500");
  width: 500px;
  height:500px
}
```

```html
<textarea>
foo
bar
</textarea>
```

Comment: @pete ..... what browser? https://jsfiddle.net/dnbxsj42/ works for me, Chrome, Edge, and IE 11 seem to have no problem.

Comment: Its not working here because the image url is a dummy url. Replace it with an actual one and it will work.

Comment: Yeah ‍♂️. Edited to use placekitten

Comment: I'm a bit new to CSS,can you please guide how to embedd CSS in HTML.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp. This w3 page will help you much rather then me explaining here

Comment: If it helped you upvote and mark it as correct so it can help others too

Comment: Thanks I was able to add image in the background of text area.A follow up question on the same..the image looks proper on desktop but on mobile browser the image doesn’t auto fits ..it goes well outside the text  ares any suggestions on how to tackle this??

Comment: This is Because of the drastic change in screen size. Using media queries might solve it